# Find dash dropdown elements with selenium (python)

Tags: python, selenium, automated-tests, dropdown, plotly-dash

I realized that dash layout elements are different from the traditional UI layout. I am trying to automate testing a dropdown element which would normally be of type "select". So the selenium syntax and select th value would be:

```
select = select(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "...")
select.select_by_visible_text("NCS")
```

I get the error: selenium.common.exceptions.UnexpectedNameTagException: Message: select only works on  elements, not on

The layout for the dropdown is as follows:
[image]
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As tag is not Select, you cant use Select class for selecting dropdown. You have to find the Select dropdown and click on that which will show dropdown list. Then you can click on desired dropdown item by providing xpath.

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "...").Click();
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[text()='Role']").Click();
```